# WCF - how to use wsHttpBinding over http, NOT https

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I wish to use WCF over straight http, and **NOT** http**s** to provide a service to service communications. Both are hosted in IIS, and both are on the same machine.

The target endpoint is an (old) asp.net web application, where I use a .svc file to host the WFC...

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="MyApp.MyWcfServiceLibrary.MyService" %>
```

I can use to the browser and I can verify that the `.svc` reaches the endpoints.

On the "client" side, I have the following in it's web.config...

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISecurityService">
      <security mode="Message">            
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

On all my test systems, all has worked fine. I now have another system where, not matter what I do to the configuration, I get a message like...

```
The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelFactory`1.ValidateScheme(Uri via) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.ValidateCreateChannelParameters(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.OnCreateChannelCore(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.OnCreateChannel(EndpointAddress remoteAddress, Uri via) at .....
```

If I log out the value of `m_serviceClient.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.ListenUri` on my system, it is always just **http**, but on the problem system, it is always **https**.

I have NO IDEA where the the `https` is coming from. I have tried everything to get rid of it. I have tried every combination of settings in the `wsHttpBinding` I can find, none work. I have read thousands of other posts, but most seem to want to go the other way (ie http -> https), and none have helped so far.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be setting the ChannelFactory to be using https, where as every other system it is just http.

Thanks in advance for any help